# Executing a function once when YouTube API iFrame hits over 75% of the video

Tags: javascript, jquery, youtube-api, frontend

I am attempting to run a function when an iFrame is playing via the YouTube API, but it executes way too many times. I have tried to flag the function with a bool to no avail. I've been stuck on this for a few hours. Please help, lol.

How can I limit this function to run only once while the video is playing?

```
    var completedMajority = false;

    function onPlayerStateChange(event, tID, tName, isThereAnExam, time) {

        if (event.data == 1) { // playing

            myTimer = setInterval( function(){ 
                var time;
                    time = player.getCurrentTime();
                    minutes = parseInt(time / 60, 10);
                    seconds = parseInt(time % 60, 10);

                    minutes = minutes < 10 ? "0" + minutes : minutes;
                    seconds = seconds < 10 ? "0" + seconds : seconds;
                    timeDuration = localStorage['timeDuration'];
                    majorityOfVid = timeDuration / 4 * 3;

                    console.log(time);
                    
                    if (!completedMajority && time >= majorityOfVid) {
                        completedMajority = true;
                        majorityOfModuleCompleted(isLive, baseURL)
                    }

                    console.log(completedMajority);

                $('#thisIsTheFinalCountdown').text(minutes + ":" + seconds);

            }, 100);
        }
        else { // not playing
            clearInterval(myTimer);
        }
```

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan Yes, time = player.getCurrentTime(); - player is the YT player

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the whole function, before your first `if`, should be wrapped in:

```
if (!completedMajority) {
 [...]
}
```